# Meteor template.rendered and this.data access

Tags: meteor

I have a template

```
<template name='order'>
  {{vendor.name}}
</template>
```

rendered with

```
  Template.order.vendor = function () {
    return {name: 'Chanel', address: 'Paris' };
  };
```

When I try to access this.data in

```
Template.order.rendered = function () {
  console.log(this.data);
};
```

I get 'undefined'.

What is the correct way of getting e.g. `vendor.name` and `vendor.address` in `Template.order.rendered`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Template.rendered, this.data corresponds to the data the template was "fed" with, either as a parameter or using the {{#with}} construct.
vendor is just a helper function returning data available in the order template, but not binded to "this.data".
SO to solve your problem, you have a number of options :

Defining a parent template and moving the vendor helper to this parent, then you can alternatively call order with vendor as a parameter or use a {{#with block}}

```
<template name="parent">
    {{> order vendor}}
    {{#with vendor}}
        {{> order}}
    {{/with}}
</template>

<template name="order">
    {{name}}
</template>

Template.parent.vendor=function(){
    return{
        name:"Chanel",
        address:"Paris"
    };
};

Template.order.rendered=function(){
    // this.data == vendor object returned in parent helper
    console.log(this.data);
};
```

You can also register a global helper, eliminating the need for an encapsulating parent template :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("vendor",function(){
    return{
        name:"Chanel",
        address:"Paris"
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for good explanation WHY this.data is available in template using `{{#with}}` or `{{#each}}` and not available when template fields are rendered with helpers. Now it's more clear to me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Template.order.rendered = function () {
    console.log(Template.order.vendor());
}
```